# Putting in ValueMember and getting ValueMember out of Listbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listbox, valuemember

Hello everyone out there! I'm trying to define the Valuemember and the Datasource of a Listbox Called "lb_Kostenstellen" (I need the ID of the Items for updating the Item in my Database) with the following statement:

```
lb_Kostenstellen.DataSource = db.Kostenstellen.ToList();
lb_Kostenstellen.ValueMember = "ID";
lb_Kostenstellen.DisplayMember = "Kostenstelle";
```

Now i created a button called "bt_Hinzufügen". When i click on the button, the Selected Item should move from my listbox called "lb_Kostenstellen" to "lb_Ausgewählt". (The item should be not visible in the first Listbox). I use this statement:

```
lb_Ausgewählt.Items.Add(lb_Kostenstellen.SelectedItem);
```

Until now, the statement works.

But now my Question: If i "switch" 3 Items from one Listbox to the Other,and then clicking on a button, I want to display 3 Messageboxes with the ID of every unique Item.

It doesn't work. I only get in the Messageboxes that:

1. MB :   I
2. MB :   D
3. MB :   (NOTHING)

   for (int i = 0; i < lb_Ausgewählt.Items.Count; i++)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(lb_Ausgewählt.ValueMember[i].ToString());
           }

I hope you have a compatible solution for me. Thanks, Daniel

My DatabaseContext is "db" (For EntityFramework).

Comment: I would suggest you to translate names in code from german to english so people also get a context your code is in. This would be a good thing to do anyway also for your local codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the string "ID" as lb_Chosen.ValueMember is a string with value "ID".

You should use something like the code below to get your IDs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lb_Chosen.Items.Count; i++) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show((lb_Chosen.Items[i] as YourAccountClass).ID.ToString()); 
}
```

Edit: translated names in code to english

Comment: Thank you very much Wonki!
But can you help me with my other Problem, please ?

Problem: When i select a LiistboxItem and click on the "switching" button, the item should move from the first Listbox to the Other Listbox. It should be invisible in the first Listbox!
I can't find a listbox property in the ListboxItem. How should i do that ? 

Greets

Comment: You should open a new question for that so that it is easy to find for other people.